# How to run Ansible commands based on versions in single task?

Tags: ansible

Can I perform these below in single task? If so, what shall be the approach?

```yaml
- name: fetch configuration
  command: "oc get disk -n **xyz** -o json"
  when: vars.version == **"2.1"**
  register: oc_result

- name: fetch configuration
  command: "oc get disk -n **abc** -o json"
  when: vars.version == **"3.0"**
  register: oc_result
```

So, if the version is `2.1`, then, the command should be run with `xyz` namespace, else with `abc` namespace.
The version will be from another YAML variable, which I will refer using `{{ vars.version }}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dictionary to match the version to a specific namespace.
And use a [`default`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.default) for the cases not in the dictionary of versions.

For example:

```yaml
- name: fetch configuration
  command: "oc get disk -n {{ _v[vars.version] | default('abc') }} -o json"
  register: oc_result
  vars:
    _v: 
      '2.1': xyz
```